# Nginx is taking the whole domain and not the subdomain

Tags: nginx

I've installed `Nginx` on a fresh EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) with a basic config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com;

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Now `Nginx` is serving both `http://atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com` and `http://kadiemqazzaz.com` but I want `Nginx` to serve only `http://atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com`.

I declared only `atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com` in the `server_name` so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a default virtual host which will handle requests to other than explicitly defined domains. An example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    return 404;
}
```